# how to fix 'jQuery is not defined' error in jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

**Rails fix**: make sure `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` is before any script loading so that jquery gets loaded first.

This seems really odd. When I load my page I get 2 js errors (in Chrome):

```
jquery-ui.min.js:17  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
jquery.blockUI.js:499  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Ok, that seems... odd. So I look at my script includes. My first two script includes on my page:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bainternet-js-cdn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jQuery%20BlockUI%20Plugin/2.39/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

So the first include is getting a javascript error related to itself? That seems unlikely. This looks like a case of a misdirection error (the real error is somewhere else). What can I do to fix this? JS errors on pages look a little unprofessional (at least to other devs). I wasn't getting this error the other day -- even reverted the code to make sure.

Comment: Where's the script tag for jQuery itself?

Comment: You must include jQuery before using jQuery UI.

Comment: `jQuery !== jQuery UI`, you have to include the "base" jQuery as well.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin hmm, checking, I haven't touched this code for a while.

Comment: @All: this looks like a rails issue, I had '//= require jquery' in my application.js but it seems to not be loading.

Comment: You can provide an answer yourself as well.

Comment: "You must include jQuery before using jQuery UI." @Mihai .. Thank you. I just realised I moved jQuery to the bottom of the page after reading this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

needs to be called before jquery ui < script > tags.

Should appear like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> <-- put me here -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://bainternet-js-cdn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jQuery%20BlockUI%20Plugin/2.39/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

Comment: Anyone having this issue in Rails should be sure and see my edit to the question that has a Rails-specific fix.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI doesn't include the standard jQuery library by default. You'll need to add a `<script>` tag to include the standard jQuery library before including any plugins that use it.