# Gmaps is not defined in production on Heroku Cedar

Tags: heroku, production, pipeline, gmaps4rails, assets

I'm new to RoR so there are many concepts that I don't understand well yet.

As my first project on rails I coded a site base on the tutorial by Michael Hartl.
My site is done in rails 3.1.0 and it works fine in dev on my ubuntu station. 
Within that site I have gmaps4rails which is loaded in gemfile that way:

```
gem 'gmaps4rails', "~> 1.4.8"
```

I have also another control called timeglider which is a javacript control that is in my public folder in /public/timeglider folder.

All this is working in dev but when i want to deploy that in production on heroku i have problem in my chrome console:

```
http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/:277Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined
http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/:182Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined
```

I invite you to go see the result of the loaded page [here](http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/).
Nothing is loaded in the gmaps section.

The problem is that Gmaps is not defined when it reach the line #277.

When I tried to fix it I read many other questions in stackoverflow about sprocket and the way it compiles the js file.

I changed my application.js from  `*= require_tree .` to

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jiffies.js
//= require gmap3.min.js
//= require jquery-1.7.1.min.js
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
//= require gmaps4rails/all_apis.js
//= require gmaps4rails/bing.js
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
```

The scripts are compile by heroku on the slug creation

You can have access to the complete application.js [here](http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/assets/application-a4d3485a82d7a76995c8b93a7477f17a.js)
You can find where the Gmaps object is defined within that script.

It's clear that there are many things that I don't understand in rails, gmaps4rails and heroku that result in a deployment problem. I am not sure that the problem comes from the asset pipeline.

I spent many nights on this bug and I'm not able to understand a clear way to debug it. Can you give me some tips to find my bug?

p.s : I'd like to post you photo and links but i'm new so there are constraints

That is the code in my view :

```
 <%= gmaps({ "map_options" => { "type" => "ROADMAP",  "zoom" => 10, "detect_location" => true,"center_on_user" => true,"auto_adjust" => false}, 
                "markers" => { "data" => @json } }) %> 
<div class='timeline-div' id='placement'></div>
```

```
$(function () { 
    var isGeoChanging = false;
    var lastGmapInfoWindowOpen = null; 
    var lastTgInfoWindowOpen = null;

    //*****************************************************
   // Code pour les évènements sur control du formulaire
   //*****************************************************
   $("#btn_change_geo").live('click', function() {
        switchGeoChanging();
    });


    switchGeoChanging = function()
    {
        if (isGeoChanging)
        { 
            $("#btn_change_geo").html("Change Jiffy's Geo");
            isGeoChanging = false;
            $("#div_change_geo_info").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#btn_change_geo").html("Cancel");
            isGeoChanging = true;
            $("#div_change_geo_info").show();
        }

    }

    //************************************************
    // Code pour les évènements sur le gmap
    //************************************************
    Gmaps.map.callback = function() 
    { 
        for (var i=0; i<this.markers.length; i++)
        {                   
                var marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject;
                marker.set("id", Gmaps.map.markers[i].id);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
                {   
                    //ici on cache les infowindow precedament ouvert pour garder la fenêtre à l'ordre
                    if (lastGmapInfoWindowOpen != null) { lastGmapInfoWindowOpen.infowindow.close();  }
                    lastGmapInfoWindowOpen = marker;
                    if (lastTgInfoWindowOpen != null) { lastTgInfoWindowOpen.hide();  }

                    //ici,si l'option est enclanché, on change la valeur du du geoId qui est associé au Jiffy
                    if (isGeoChanging)
                    {
                        switchGeoChanging();
                        $("#txt_geo_id").val(this.get("id"));
                        callAjaxGet("http://localhost:3000/jiffies/"+this.get('id')+"/getGeo");
                    }

                } );        
        }
        marker = null;
    };

    callAjaxGet = function(url)
    {
        $.ajax(url, {
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {  },
                        success: function() { },
                        error: function() { alert("Impossible de charger le Jiffy."); }
                    }); 
    }


    //************************************************
    //  code pour les évènements sur le timeglider
    //************************************************
    $(".timeline-table").css({"display":"block"});


    var tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({
            "min_zoom":5, 
            "max_zoom":50, 
            "show_centerline":true,
            "data_source":"#jiffies_table",
            "show_footer":false,
            "display_zoom_level":true,
            "event_overflow":"scroll",
            "icon_folder":"http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/icons/"
    });





    $("#scrolldown").bind("click", function() {
        $(".timeglider-timeline-event").animate({top:"+=100"})
    });

    $("#scrollup").bind("click", function() {
        $(".timeglider-timeline-event").animate({top:"-=100"})
    });

    <%= @js_jiffies.html_safe%>



}); // end document-ready
```

Comment: what's the code in your view?

Comment: Just to clarify, this div <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map" ... which I find in my page when the code works well is made by the gmaps4rails plugin in the view or in the javascript?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. It started happenening around the time I started messing with the asset pipeline and memcache on Heroku. Going to roll back to an earlier commit and see what in the world is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Web page http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/, there are many javascript files have URL paths that look like the code below. http://localhost:3000 will work on your Dev machine, but won't work on Heroku.

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Date.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Org.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Timeline.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_TimelineView.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Mediator.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/timeglider.timeline.widget.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

EDIT. From Chrome's console

> Failed to load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/css/aristo/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.cssFailed
>   to load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/Timeglider.cssFailed to
>   load resource
>   application-a4d3485a82d7a76995c8b93a7477f17a.js:315Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/jquery.jsFailed to load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/jquery-ui.jsFailed to load
>   resource http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/underscore-min.jsFailed
>   to load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/backbone-min.jsFailed to load
>   resource http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/jquery.tmpl.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/ba-debug.min.jsFailed to load
>   resource http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/ba-tinyPubSub.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/jquery.ui.ipad.jsFailed to load
>   resource http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/raphael-min.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/jquery.global.jsFailed to load
>   resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Date.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Org.jsFailed to load
>   resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Timeline.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_TimelineView.jsFailed
>   to load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/TG_Mediator.jsFailed to
>   load resource
>   http://localhost:3000/timeglider/js/timeglider/timeglider.timeline.widget.jsFailed
>   to load resource
>   http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/assets/defaults.jsFailed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/:149Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not
>   defined http://geojiffy.herokuapp.com/:277Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   Gmaps is not defined

Comment: You'r right for the timeglider section thank you, but i'm stil stock on the gmaps bug.

Comment: gmaps isn't loading because jQuery javascript file isn't loading.

Comment: You're right, to be clearer, Gmaps doesn't need jQuery but it needs files load.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was a beginer one, thank you all for the tips. The clue comes from jquery reference error.  When you load a script in the asset pipeline you must also take care of the order of your loading. You can see a similar problem there but not in Asset Pipeline.
[jquery is not define error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266657/how-to-fix-jquery-is-not-defined-error-in-jquery-library)
So that's the good order in my application.js within my app:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-1.7.1.min.js 
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
//= require jiffies.js
//= require gmaps4rails/all_apis.js
//= require gmaps4rails/bing.js
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
//= require gmap3.min.js//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-1.7.1.min.js 
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
//= require jiffies.js
//= require gmaps4rails/all_apis.js
//= require gmaps4rails/bing.js
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js
//= require gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
//= require gmap3.min.js
```

You can see that first jquery then jquery-ui after that all the apis in the dir  gmaps4rails/ and finally the gmaps.min.js

Also  `//= require_tree .` is'n good in production. You have to write down all your script path required: //= require PATH_TO_THE_SCRIPT.

Merci

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly logic: your `application.js` file doesn't load because they're is one error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

That's why `Gmaps` isn't defined afterwards. Fix your js dependencies.

Comment: Any idea what would be causing that? I'm having similar problems and in my application.js it would appear everything *should* be ok...

Comment: @tibbon: I guess you forgot some files in the pipeline or you didn't precompile them properly