# Why does jQuery stop working after precompiling if I mess with js files in assets?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I created `new.js` in `assets/javascripts/` and added this into `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'new.js' %>
```

Then I executed

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

After this, jQuery stops working.
What could be the cause of this and how would I fix it?

UPDATE:

application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include this script separetelly, then you should add it to your environment configuration.

```
config.assets.precompile += %w{ new.js }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I rolled back to the situation before. So I deleted `new.js` file, and the line in `views/layouts/application.html.erb` Then I did `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` again. However, jQuery won't come back. That's why I'm so confused:(

Comment: Can't I delete `precompile related files` and redo again??

Comment: I'll paste all. what kind of files do you need to see? only application.js?

Comment: Yes, I have this `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js' %>`

Comment: on web browser, it shows `<script src="/assets/application-a9ba0fbc97cb6e5f7e03b516a031d93d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` look fine:(

Comment: If I click on the link it shows the content of that saying `/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/`.....

Comment: I executed `bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production` then  `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` again. but still the same:(

Comment: I created `new.js` on my own, and put in javascripts directory. I didn't use command. Does it matter??

Comment: Is there any to check??:( I have no idea what to check:(

Comment: Now I see this error ` ReferenceError: sample is not defined.  SourceFile: javascript:%20sample` Does this give us any hint?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266657/how-to-fix-jquery-is-not-defined-error-in-jquery-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553343/why-is-jquery-not-loading-in-my-rails-3-2-3-app